# CodeIgniter pagination with order by and search

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

How can I make the pagination not reset the sorting from page 1? Because when I order the table, it will be reset on the next page. How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
public function viewstudents(){
        $this->pagination('students');

        $studedit = $this->session->userdata('studedit_id');
        if(isset($studedit)){
            $this->session->unset_userdata('studedit_id');
        }

        $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

        $userdata['user'] = $this->UsersModel->select_admin($id);
        $this->load->view('include/header_admin', $userdata);

        $data['students'] = $this->UsersModel->getStudents(10, $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['page'] = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $msg = $this->session->userdata('msg');
        if(isset($msg)){
            $data['msg'] = $msg;
        }

        $this->load->view('admin/view_students', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer_admin');
    }
```

And the pagination function:

```
public function pagination($table) {
            $this->load->library('pagination');

            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/view'.$table;
            $config['per_page'] = 10;
            $config['num_links'] = 3;
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get($table)->num_rows();
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['first_link'] = '<span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> First';
            $config['last_link'] = 'Last <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>';
            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    }
```

I believe it's in the `$config['base_url']` so I tried changing it to

`$config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/view'.$table.'?sortby='.$sort.'&direction='.$dir;`

but still, the pagination doesn't set in the next page.

Comment: If you've sorted the table, I'd recommend sending the sort data to the page as well. Then when going to a different page, pass the sort data as well and use it to sort the data being sent.

Comment: You should store sort order in session to be able to have it on the next request (page).

Comment: @JeremyJackson What do you mean send the sort data to the page?

Comment: I think @Tpojka's idea is better. A session variable would work. And I meant you could send something like `$data['sortData']` to the page and send it up in the next page request, but a session variable would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. What I did was to add `$config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;`

Comment: can you please explain me to do ajax sorting along with search.